# Will a persisted-dataframe be calculated repeatedly many times?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've got the following structured query:

```
val A = 'load somedata from  HDFS'.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
val B = A.filter('condition 1')
val C = A.filter('condition 2')
val D = A.filter('condition 3')
val E = A.filter('condition 4')
val F = A.filter('condition 5')
val G = A.filter('condition 6')
val H = A.filter('condition 7')

val I = B.union(C).union(D).union(E).union(F).union(G).union(H)
```

I persist the dataframe A, so that when I use B/C/D/E/F/G/H, the A dataframe should be calculated only once? But the DAG of this job is below:

[image]

From the DAG above, it seems that stage 6-12 are all executed and the dataframe A is calculated 7 times?

Why would this happen?

Maybe the DAG is just fake? I found that there are not lines on the top of stage 7-12 where stage 6 does have two lines from  other stage

I didn't list all the operations. After `union` operation, I save the `I` dataframe to HDFS. Will this action on the `I` dataframe make the persist operation be done really? Or must I do an action operation such as `count` on the `A` dataframe to trigger the persist operation before reuse `A` dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing the following line won't persist your dataset.

```
val A = 'load somedata from  HDFS'.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
```

Caching/persistence is lazy when used with Dataset API so you have to trigger the caching using `count` operator or similar that in turn submits a Spark job.

After that all the following operators, `filter` including, should use **InMemoryTableScan** with the green dot in the plan (as shown below).

[image]

In your case even after `union` the dataset `I` is not cached since you have not triggered the caching (but merely marked it for caching).

> After union operation, I save the `I` dataframe to HDFS. Will this action on the `I` dataframe make the persist operation be done really?

Yes. Only actions (like saving to an external storage) can trigger the persistence for future reuse.

> Or must I do an action operation such as count on the `A` dataframe to trigger the persist operation before reuse `A` dataframe?

That's the point! In your case, since you want to reuse `A` dataframe across `filter` operators you should `persist` it first, `count` (to trigger the caching) followed by `filter`s.

In your case, no `filter` will benefit from any performance increase due to `persist`. That `persist` is practically void of any impact on the performance and just makes a code reviewer think it's otherwise.

If you want to see when and if your dataset is cached, you can check out **Storage** tab in web UI or ask `CacheManager` about it.

```
val nums = spark.range(5).cache
nums.count
scala> spark.sharedState.cacheManager.lookupCachedData(nums)
res0: Option[org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CachedData] =
Some(CachedData(Range (0, 5, step=1, splits=Some(8))
,InMemoryRelation [id#0L], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
   +- *Range (0, 5, step=1, splits=8)
))
```

Comment: does dataframes maintain linage as like RDDs ?